# install Modem Driver BCMWL for a specific Kernel only out of many

Tags: drivers, apt, kernel, broadcom, modem

I have 3 Kernels installed on my focal fossa

- 5.4.0-26-generic
- 5.4.0-54-generic
- unsigned-5.9.0-050900-generic

Initially, My BCMWL proprietary drivers 6.30.223.271 are working fine in 5.4.0-26-generic, 5.4.0-54-generic.
But when I installed new Kernel unsigned-5.9.0-050900-generic, I just realized the BCMWL drivers are not patched yet and BCMWL drivers errors out in kernel v5.9.

When I re-install the BCMWL drivers in 5.4.0-26-generic, it re-deploys for all the kernels and errors out in Kernel v5.9 and so I could not activate it in kernels v5.4.
As a result it does not work in all 3 kernels - now I don't have internet.

Is there a way to install against only a particular kernel v5.4 (ABI 26,54) without affecting other kernels, so that it does not get activated for kernel v5.9?

I install BCMWL drivers using command
$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to remove the `5.9` kernel, then install `bcmwl-kernel-source`, then install the `5.9` kernel back.

Another way would be to extract the contents of the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package and install the dkms driver manually. But this looks more complex to me.

Comment: Kernel v5.9 installation errors out if the system has Proprietary drivers like BCMWL, wiki.ubuntu says that "if you do not uninstall these Proprietary modules first, then the upstream kernel may fail to install, or boot". So, this is like catch 22 situation. so, the Option 1 is not possible. I wish kernel could be passed as parameter to apt install command.

Comment: Did you try it? There may be an error, but the kernel should install. Anyway it is possible to build `wl` for specific kernels without using dkms. The question how to do it the easiest way.

Comment: yeah .. i have tried it - first with a stable system that has everything working (BCMWL and NVIDIA), and tried to install Kernel v5.9 it errors and did not boot, had a black screen - nvidia driver issue. so removed all Proprietary drivers and installed new Kernel and then installed drivers

Comment: This was a pure Nvidia issue ;-) If you install only `wl`, it will boot. Also you can uninstall `nvidia` from a specific kernel using `dkms remove -k <kernel version>`